# error while SELECT column with numerical fraction included in column name --myqsql

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

my problem is that the Left Outer Join shown below works totally fine as long as I do not include the columns `bp.frac_4/8` and `bp2.frac_4/8_2`.
I tried several varieties, including `'bp.frac_4/8'`, `bp.frac_"4/8"`, `bp.frac_'+'4/8`, etc.
Either I got the error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'frac_4' in 'field list'
```

or it just gave me the column with `frac_4/8` written out in each row.
How can I solve this problem?

```
SELECT bp.person_id, DATE(bp.recentDate), bp.amount, bp2.amount2, bp.frac_4/8,
bp2.frac_4/8_2
FROM bestper bp
LEFT JOIN bestper2 bp2
ON bp.person_id=bp2.person_id AND DATE(bp.recentDate)=DATE(bp2.recentDate)
ORDER BY  DATE(bp.recentDate) DESC
```

Comment: Just a heads up.. You might want to come up with a better naming convention for your column names. frac_4 is a poor name. It will make things harder for people picking up on your code.

Answer (score 2):

use backtick to escape in `mySQL`

example

```
SELECT bp.`frac_4/8`,...
FROM...
```

Comment: damn !! you win me by 10 seconds.. +1 for been faster and correct

Comment: Oh man!! That works. I never tried backticks just for the column name, stupid me....Thanks alot, that was fast and clean help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes with ANSI SQL mode enabled or back ticks.